# force http to https with an egsisting acces file

Tags: .htaccess

I dont know much about htaccess files and i was hoping you can help me.

I have this file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond &#37;{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?d-hive.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/d-hive/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /d-hive/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?d-hive.net$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ d-hive/index.php [L]
```

I was wondering how can i force the page to open up the HTTPS protocol instead of the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

use full url e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ https://www.d-hive.net/index.php [L]
```

Plus, can include

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
```

so something like,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ https://www.d-hive.net/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rules like this. Let me know how this works for.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?d-hive\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/d-hive/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /d-hive/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?d-hive\.net$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ d-hive/index.php [L]
```

Comment: It works for www. but not for non www adress. Dunno if its the cache or what. ill try again later. thanks :)

Comment: It should work for either one. Try and clear your cache or try in a different browser.